# How can I use a data variable within a postman endpoint URL that is not a query parameter?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have an endpoint URL such as [https://example.com/{{variable}}.json](https://example.com/%7B%7Bvariable%7D%7D.json) . I would like to use Collection Runner in Postman to run multiple requests to that endpoint, and upload a CSV file with multiple IDs to appear in place of that variable in the endpoint URL.

I can do this if the variable appears in the body of the request or within query parameters, but I cannot figure out how to do this if the variable is placed in the URL itself in this format.

If I use a collection/environment/global variable, it simply places the saved data into the URL, rather than data from the uploaded CSV using Collection Runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are having `variable` in the first row of your csv file as below. and remove `variable` from your collection/environment/global variables.

```
variable
123 
456 
789
```

In postman runner, select the collection and load the csv file in data, set the iterations to the required number.

Now when you run the collection, each iteration will take a new value from the csv file.

Refer this [blog](https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my issue! The variable was also set as a Global variable.