# Calling a Variable from a JSON File for use in Postman Tests

Tags: json, get, postman, postman-collection-runner

My test URL looks like this:

`{{baseURL}}/api/v1/{{testName}}`

When I run this test in the runner, it does not pull in the `testName` variable.

My json data file looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "testName": "12345"
    {
      "test1": "1234",
      "test2": "2468"
    },
    {
      "test1": "1357",
      "test2": "9876"
    },
  "testName": "2468"
    {
      "test1": "1234",
      "test2": "2468"
    },
    {
      "test1": "1357",
      "test2": "9876"
    }
  }
]
```

But this doesn't work.

So I am trying to call the variable from the `.json` file in the runner, then proceed to check the expected data against the actual data from the request. Then when finished the one test, will then proceed to the next test.

Comment: This is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260593/how-can-i-use-a-data-variable-within-a-postman-endpoint-url-that-is-not-a-query?rq=1; however, my question relates to using the JSON file.

Comment: `pm.iterationData.get("myVariable");` will help you get value from csv/json file. Then set it  a global/environment variables.

Comment: Thanks @lucas-nguyen-17, but how do I write it in my `.json` file? That is where I am getting confused.

Comment: You can write it in pre-request of collection/folder. Haven't tested yet. More info here https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/working-with-data-files/

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the datafile would be like this simple example:

```json
[
    {
        "testName": "12345"
    },
    {
        "testName": "2468"
    }
]
```

When used in the Collection Runner, the `{{testName}}` variable in the URL, would be resolved to the value in the object.

Each of the objects in the array, within the JSON file, is an iteration. So for the first run, it would pick up `12345` and in the second run it would pick up `2468`.

If you would need to check the expected data in the file in an iteration, the structure would need to look like this:

```json
[
    {
        "testName": "12345",
        "test1": "1234",
        "test2": "2468"
    },
    {
        "testName": "2468",
        "test1": "0987",
        "test2": "4567"
    }
]
```

I'm not aware of your full use case here so this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks Danny. The problem I have is that in my example above, the first variable `12345` has multiple data returned. Then the second would be the same, etc. I need Postman to call each variable `testName` and do the tests matching the data objects. i.e. Call `testName1` > do tests; call `testName2` > do tests, etc.

Comment: When I run it through Postman, I am getting this error: `JSONError: No data, empty input at 1:1^` where my URL is `http://example.com/api/v1/%7B%7BtestName%7D%7D`

Comment: Without more context, that kinda means nothing to me apart from it looks like it's URL encoding the `{{testName}}` variable. The data file will only work with the runner so unless you have another variable with the same name, set in a different scope, it's not going to resolve to anything.